# How to set TTL with Cassandra COPY command

Tags: cassandra, copy, cql, ttl

I can import a chunk of data into `Cassandra` table with `COPY` command like:

```
COPY my_table (name, address) FROM my_file.csv WITH option='value' ... ;
```

But I want them to have a finite `TTL` set (e.g., 1 day or 86400 seconds) when I create the table with `COPY` command.  How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Currently there's no way to do this, but this would be a useful feature requrest so you should create a JIRA.

From the cqlsh tool's source:

```
COPY <table_name> [ ( column [, ...] ) ]
             TO ( '<filename>' | STDOUT )
             [ WITH <option>='value' [AND ...] ];

        Available options and defaults:

          DELIMITER=','    - character that appears between records
          QUOTE='"'        - quoting character to be used to quote fields
          ESCAPE='\'       - character to appear before the QUOTE char when quoted
          HEADER=false     - whether to ignore the first line
          NULL=''          - string that represents a null value
          ENCODING='utf8'  - encoding for CSV output (COPY TO only)
```

The [bulk-loader](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/bulk-loading) allows for insertion with TTL but that adds the overhead of having to generate sstables to bulk load.

Comment: Thanks. Where can we create Cassandra JIRA for new feature?

Comment: @genesco [Apache jira](https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/CreateIssue!default.jspa) requires you to log in. Make sure to select the cassandra project. All the best!

Answer (score -1):

TTL option via COPY FROM command will do the trick here. ( Note - This option is only available in Cassandra 3.2 and above)

https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/new-features-in-cqlsh-copy